# How to insert into a table where a column has a specified value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am probably overthinking this, but how would you insert a value into a column for a table where another specified column is equal to a specified value? Something is not working with the below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[bcasp_InsertDate]
@TicketNum nvarchar(250),
@DateFinal datetime

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT DateFinalEmailSent FROM T_Ticket WHERE TicketNumber = @TicketNumber
INSERT INTO T_Table(DateFinalEmailSent) VALUES (@DateFinal)
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code as written isn't working because you're not assigning a value to `@DateFinal` in your first `SELECT` statement, but that statement, and the accompanying variable, are really unnecessary.

Why not just a straight `INSERT`?

```
INSERT INTO T_Table
(
  DateFinalEmailSent
)
SELECT 
  DateFinalEmailSent 
FROM 
  T_Ticket 
WHERE 
  TicketNumber = @TicketNumber;
```

Comment: Sorry, `@DateFinal` (and `@TicketNumber`) gets filled through ASP.Net so its not an issue. But your solutions works; thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the below change in your code in order to make it work.

```
SELECT @DateFinal= DateFinalEmailSent FROM T_Ticket WHERE TicketNumber = @TicketNumber
```